# Image Preview on Drag and Drop not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drag and drop script with an image preview div. When I drag and drop an image over to the label or div it works except it doesn't display the image. It shows a broken image link. And if I check it in the `console.log` it says `GET http://localhost/site/null 404 (Not Found)`. 
I need the image to preview when dropped into the `.media_drop` div.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="media_drop" onchange="preview_image(event)" onclick="imageViewer()">
  <label for="file" id="label_input"></label>
    <input class="media_file" type="file" id="file"  name="" accept="image/*">
</div><!-- End of media_drop -->
```

And:

```
$(function(){
var reader = new FileReader();

var media_drop = $('.media_drop');
var label_input = $('label_input');
var image_file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

      media_drop.on('dragover', function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).css('background', 'slategrey');
      $(this).css('border', 'red 2px solid'); 
      });

      media_drop.on('drop', function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();

      var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];

      var output = document.querySelector('.image_preview');
      output.src = reader.result;
      //console.log(images);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    $('.image_preview').css('display', 'block');
    $('.media_drop').css('display', 'none');   
    $('label_input').css('display', 'none');

      }); 
});
```

I will appreciate any help. 
TIA

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @huraji Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/masoodbawa/pen/vYBwzzK

Comment: I read `$ is not defined` in the console

Comment: I'll add to jsfiddle instead. Doesn't seem to be working in codepen

Comment: I I include jQuery in codepen it works fine. Make sure that jQuery is on top before your js code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/masoodbawa/d06fpen9/

Please use the jsfiddle instead.

Comment: There isn't the javascript in fiddle...

Comment: I just saved the fiddle now. I think I might have forgotten to save it.

Comment: I repeat, in codepen if you set the jQuery library, works well.

Comment: I did so. Strange it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I added the Google CDN of Jquery, above the js code.